# TextExpander, Shell Scripts, & Node

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, textexpander

I'm trying to execute some JS code as a Node shell script, but it doesn't seem to work and I can't tell why. Here's a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("foo");
```

The above script should result in TextExpander inserting the text "foo" when triggered, but it doesn't. The equivalent in bash works just as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "foo"
```

I thought that perhaps the call to `console.log()` was not producing something where TextExpander was looking (although all the documentation I can find says that should print to stdout). I've even tried a workaround like this with no luck:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo `/usr/bin/env node -e "console.log(\"foo\");"`
```

I get no visible errors or any indication that something went wrong. I just end up with TextExpander inserting an empty string instead of `"foo"`. Any TextExpander experts out that that might see something I'm missing? Running the non-working examples in the shell work fine, and TextExpander is supposed to just capture whatever goes to stdout. I'm not even sure how I could go about debugging this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the directory where your `node` executable is installed is listed in the PATH environment variable that TextExpander will use. This is probably not the same PATH value one you get in your terminal. To verify if that's the problem, try doing `#!/full/path/to/node` as your shebang line instead of running `env`. My guess is node is installed either in `/usr/local/bin/node` or somewhere under your home directory and neither of those are in the PATH that TextExpander has while running.

Comment: This was exactly the issue! Specifying the full path to my node executable got it working exactly as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably should add `-e` to your header:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node -e
```

Or

You probably should add -e to your header:

```
#!/path/to/node -e
```